# I'm trying to Junit test method that returns Map object of the following structure: Map<List<int[]>>, Enum> foo. Whats the right way to do it?

Tags: java

The thing is, that Junit compares these map results as object instance and hence fails the test all the time, even if Lists contains right arrays of ints coupling with right Enum.
My code is smth like that, and I want Assert to return true.

```
Logic <Map<List<int[]>, Enum>> logic = new FooLogic(2, field, new StandardRules(PlaceHolders.getPlaceHolders()));
Map<List<int[]>, Enum> freeCells = logic.executeLogic();
Map<List<int[]>, Enum> expected = new LinkedHashMap<>();
expected.put(new ArrayList<>(List.of(new int[]{0, 0}, new int[]{0, 1})), Directions.EAST);
expected.put(new ArrayList<>(List.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{0, 0})), Directions.WEST);
Assert.assertThat(freeCells, Is.is(expected));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ArrayList` (`AbstractList` to be more precise) uses `equals` to compare elements, and arrays don't override `equals`. So `assertTrue(new int[]{0, 0}.equals(new int[]{0, 0}));` fails as well as `assertThat(Lists.of(new int[]{0, 0}), is(Lists.of(new int[]{0, 0})));`.

It's a bad idea to use arrays (or lists of arrays) as `Map` keys because most of the maps also use `equals`, so it will not only be hard to test the outcome of that method, but it's also will be difficult to use it in production:

```
int[] key = {0};
Map<int[], String> map = Maps.of(new Pair<>(key, "value"));
assertThat(map.get(key), is("value")); // passes
assertThat(map.get(new int[]{0}), is("value")); // fails
```

For solving this problem I recommend replacing `Map<List<int[]>, Enum>` with `Map<List<List<Integer>>, Enum<?>>`:

```
List<Integer> key = Lists.of(1);
Map<List<Integer>, String> map = Maps.of(new Pair<>(key, "value"));
assertThat(map.get(key), is("value")); // passes
assertThat(map.get(Lists.of(1)), is("value")); // passes
```

---

If you really want to keep `Map<List<int[]>, Enum>`, you can test its content manually:

```
Set<Entry<List<int[]>, Enum<?>>> entries = freeCells.entrySet();
Iterator<Entry<List<int[]>, Enum<?>>> entryIterator = entries.iterator();
assertEntryEquals(entryIterator.next(), Lists.of(new int[]{0, 0}, new int[]{0, 1}), Directions.EAST);
assertEntryEquals(entryIterator.next(), Lists.of(new int[]{0, 1}, new int[]{0, 0}), Directions.WEST);
assertFalse(entryIterator.hasNext());
```

```
private static void assertEntryEquals(Entry<List<int[]>, Enum<?>> entry, List<int[]> key, Enum<?> value) {
    assertThat(entry.getValue(), is(value));
    Iterator<int[]> original = entry.getKey().iterator();
    for (int[] expected : key) assertArrayEquals(original.next(), expected);
    assertFalse(original.hasNext());
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot. I finally got it!